# Command to erase a file permanently

Tags: mac, trash

There is a command to erase a file without send it to the trash?

I am pretty sure that i don't need some files anymore.
I want to clean my storage. Do I need to send those files to the trash?

Comment: Do you mean something other than the `rm` command?

Comment: Can i select my files and use this command?

I'm starting with MacBooks.
My brother gave me his old one and told me i can erase all files.

Comment: @vanedias So you mean delete from Finder? - although in the case you five I would create a new user for you and delete your brother as a user

Comment: Yes, i mean from finder, thanks, i will try delete his account.

:D

Comment: Ah, to delete an account, you can just open System Preferences and delete the account including its files from there.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how confident you're going to be using Terminal commands as a brand new user, so I wouldn't recommend doing anything that can permanently, no questions asked, delete data from your hard drive.

It would be far safer to delete files to the Trash using the standard Finder command
 <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Backspace ←</kbd>  .

Then when you are happy you really didn't need the files, again from the Finder
 <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>    <kbd>Backspace ←</kbd>    will empty the trash.

That in itself wouldn't securely erase, preventing all recovery efforts; but from a standard user perspective, they would be gone & the hard disk space freed up to be used again.

Comment: You could then use Disk Utility, or from Terminal, `diskutil` to erase the free space on the volume from at a minimum of writing zeros or stronger level of erasure.

Comment: Sure - though it could be on an SSD... really I just wanted to avoid a new user wanting free reign with dangerous stuff like `sudo rm -rf`

Comment: I agree, and if it's an SSD, I would do any unnecessary free space erasures.

Comment: There is the additional 'you really ought to wipe the entire machine & start over as its new owner' argument, I just thought that was too far beyond the brief of the question.

Comment: Yes, I would have already none that and started fresh.  BTW, I left out the "not" if front of "would" in my last comment.